# r data.table lapply with multiple SDcols

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to use an lapply that takes two lists of columns into account (all are numeric type) in what would seem to be a simple line of code, but the output is not as expected.

This is my code :

```
x<-50

measure <- c("haz", "waz", "whz", "htcm", "wtkg", "bmi")
new_measure_1.5 <- paste(measure, "1.5", sep = "_")
new_temp_cols<-paste("temp", new_measure_1.5, sep = "_")
new_columns<-paste(new_measure_1.5, "1", sep="_")

newcols_1.5_months<-function(x, agedays, new_temp_cols, y){
    ifelse(agedays==x, new_temp_cols, y)
  }

DT[, (new_columns) := lapply(.SD, function(y) newcols_1.5_months(x, agedays, new_temp_cols, y)), .SDcols = new_columns ]
```

The above code results in new_columns (haz_1.5_1,  waz_1.5_1, whz_1.5_1, wtkg_1.5_1,  htcm_1.5_1, bmi_1.5_1) holding the names of the columns in the list new_temp_cols (temp_haz_1.5,  temp_waz_1.5, temp_whz_1.5, temp_wtkg_1.5,  temp_htcm_1.5, temp_bmi_1.5) as opposed to the values they hold in my data table. It seems that R is reading the list as a vector of strings rather than a vector of columns. Why is this?

I've tried using multiple .SDcols, but this doesn't  work :

```
DT[, (new_columns) := lapply(.SD, function(y) newcols_1.5_months(x, agedays, new_temp_cols, y)), .SDcols = c(new_columns, new_temp_cols) ]
```

Is there a simple fix to this?

**** Editing to add a small subset of dummy data similar to my data table

```
measure<-c("haz", "waz")
new_measure_1.5 <- paste(measure, "1.5", sep = "_")
new_temp_cols<-paste("temp", new_measure_1.5, sep = "_")
new_columns<-paste(new_measure_1.5, "1", sep="_")


anthro <- data.table

    (agedays = c(25,50,53,22,37,50,12,45,50,15,33,50),
                               temp_haz_1.5 = c(1.2,1.5,1.7,2.0,4.5,6.7,6.8,6.7,4.5,6.6,8.9,6.7),
                               temp_waz_1.5 = c(3.2,1.8,6.7,2.8,3.5,7.7,9.8,1.7,6.9,3.8,0.9,4.7),
                   haz_1.5_1 = c(1.2,2.5,4.7,7.0,4.7,6.8,6.3,2.7,5.5,8.6,3.9,6.7),  
                   waz_1.5_1 =c(6.2,2.5,5.7,7.0,2.5,7.7,8.8,9.7,2.5,4.6,5.9,6.7))
```

Comment: (1) You mention `new_measure_3.5` but define `new_measure_1.5`, typo? (2) `new_columns` explicitly contains those names, so it makes sense that `data.table` would keep these. Sample data will be informative here.

Comment: @r2evans yes it is a typo! Sorry, that's embarrassing. I just edited my post to fix that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @akrun Just edited the post to add in some dummy data

Comment: can you please check my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have multiple columns, then use `Map` to loop over each of the corresponding sets of columns and apply the function.

```
library(data.table)
x <- 50
DT[, (new_columns) := Map(function(u, y) 
    newcols_1.5_months(u, DT[['agedays']], x, y),
    .SD[, new_columns, with = FALSE], 
       .SD[, new_temp_cols, with = FALSE]) ]
```

Perhaps the function can be

```
newcols_1.5_months<- function(u, agedays, x,  y){
      ifelse(agedays==x, u, y)
   }
```

#### data

```
DT <- data.table(agedays = c(25,50,53,22,37,50,12,45,50,15,33,50),
                               temp_haz_1.5 = c(1.2,1.5,1.7,2.0,4.5,6.7,6.8,6.7,4.5,6.6,8.9,6.7),
                                temp_waz_1.5 = c(3.2,1.8,6.7,2.8,3.5,7.7,9.8,1.7,6.9,3.8,0.9,4.7),
                    haz_1.5_1 = c(1.2,2.5,4.7,7.0,4.7,6.8,6.3,2.7,5.5,8.6,3.9,6.7),  
                    waz_1.5_1 =c(6.2,2.5,5.7,7.0,2.5,7.7,8.8,9.7,2.5,4.6,5.9,6.7))
```

Comment: since x is given prior to the function for the agedays value (x==50), should I add in another variable in place of x? Wouldn't this just carry x (50) through new_columns ?

Comment: I ran the code and the cells where agedays==x just hold NA values in new_columns

Comment: @boodaloo1  I understand the question that you have two sets of columns, which you want to compare if the 'agedays' column is equal to the first set of columns, replace with the values of second set

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I basically want to replace one set of columns if agedays==x with another set of columns. i.e. if agedays==50, then haz_1.5_1 == temp_haz_1.5 else haz_1.5_1==haz_1.5_1

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here, but I guess I just don't understand how you wouldn't need another variable besides x. i.e. the code is written as ifelse(agedays==x, y, x)… since x is defined as 50 prior to the function, wouldn't this then mean if agedays==50, then new_columns == new_temp_cols else new_columns==50 ,rather than new_columns==new_columns (holding their original value) ?

Comment: @boodaloo1 okay.  So that is the confusion.  I will change

Comment: @boodaloo1 your naming of the columns are creating more confusion.  Let's say if the 'agedays ==50, you want to replace the values in columns 'new_columns' with correspoinding values of 'new_temp_cols' or else 50?

Comment: sorry about the column names. The logic would be as follows : if agedays==50, then new_columns == new_temp_cols else new_columns == new_columns

Comment: I updated the function.  Please check if that works

Comment: I'm still just getting NA values in the new_columns rather than the values held in new_temp_cols

Comment: @boodaloo1 with your example I am not getting any NA values

Comment: I came back to my code this morning and was able to fix the NA values. The only issue was that the two lines of variables (new_columns and new_temp_cols) were out of order. I swapped the order and it worked. Quick fix! Thanks for all your help!